# Why does flake8 give the warning F821 -- undefined name 'match' when using match.group(0) with Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, flake8

Please consider the following example, which finds the first String in a list that contains the Substring "OH":

```
list = ["STEVE", "JOHN", "YOANN"]
pattern = re.compile(".*%s.*" % "OH")
word = ""

if any((match := pattern.match(item)) for item in list):
    word = match.group(0)
print(word)
```

The code works as intended and outputs "JOHN", but I am getting the following warning from flake8 at the line `word = match.group(0)`:

```
F821 -- undefined name 'match'
```

Why is this happening, and can I remove the warning without command line arguments or disabling all F821 errors?

Comment: Try `flake8 --disable-noqa` or `flake8 --ignore=F821` should work.

Comment: what version of `flake8` are you using?

Comment: @gold_cy flake8 3.9.2 (mccabe: 0.6.1, pycodestyle: 2.7.0, pyflakes: 2.3.1) CPython 3.9.5 on Windows

Comment: @MaNKuR as I put in my last paragraph, I'd rather not ignore all F821 warnings.

Comment: @Paul My gut feeling says the flake8 has no ability to recognize the new variable assignment introduced in `Python3.8`. So either you have to wait until the feature introduced or change the code to use old-style or manually ignore those statements.

Comment: @MaNKuR Thank you, you're probably right.

Comment: it says that newest versions should support the walrus operator, and you have the newest versions of these packages

Comment: @gold_cy Can you try to reproduce the issue? Maybe it's only on my side.

Comment: have you tried adding an inline comment `noqa: F821` next to the line? `word = match.group(0) # noqa: F821` ? like so

Comment: @python_user If the condition fails, then match.group(0) is never called, so that shouldn't cause a warning. The inline comment removes the warning, thank you for that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a bug in [pyflakes](https://github.com/pycqa/pyflakes) -- I'd suggest reporting it there

The subtlety is that assignment expressions break out of comprehension scopes, but pyflakes assumes that comprehension scopes enclose all assignments

I'd suggest reporting an issue [here](https://github.com/pycqa/pyflakes/issues)

as a workaround, you can place a `# noqa` comment on the line which produces the error, for example:

```py
# this one ignores *all* errors on the line
word = match.group(0)  # noqa
```

```py
# this one ignores specifically the F821 error
word = match.group(0)  # noqa: F821
```

---

disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of flake8 and one of the maintainers of pyflakes

Comment: For future readers: the fix for this has been merged with this PR --> https://github.com/PyCQA/pyflakes/pull/698